# count hibernate and Named Query

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to count elements from table using NamedQueries.

NamedQuery is:

```
@NamedQuery(name = Advertisement.countBySubcategoryList, query = "select count(*) from  Advertisement where subcategoryId IN (:subcategoryId)")
```

and:

```
public static final String countBySubcategoryList = "Advertisement.countBySubcategoryList";
```

In model I use:

```
List<Advertisement> advertisements = session.getNamedQuery(Advertisement.countBySubcategoryList)
            .setParameterList("subcategoryId", subcategoryIds)
            .list();
```

How to get count value from query?

Comment: Spring is irrelevant for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should be something like

```
select count(a) from Advertisement a where a.subcategoryId IN (:subcategoryId)
```

And you should call it like this

```
Long count = (Long)session.getNamedQuery(Advertisement.countBySubcategoryList)
            .setParameterList("subcategoryId", subcategoryIds)
            .uniqueResult();
```

**EDIT**

Hibernate versions prior to 4 returned `Integer` instead of `Long` for this type of query.

Comment: You missed the type cast. And it will return an `Integer`, not a `Long`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks, fixed the cast. But, return type actually depends on Hibernate version, in 4.x it returns `Long`.

Answer (score 1):

You can even try this, if you are hibernate version < 4

> int count =
>   ((Number)em.createNamedQuery("Advertisement.countBySubcategoryList").getSingleResult()).intValue();

if you are hibernate version >= 4 . @Maric is right

> Long count =
>   (Long)session.getNamedQuery(Advertisement.countBySubcategoryList)
>               .setParameterList("subcategoryId", subcategoryIds)
>               .uniqueResult();